# God of War 2 - What to do with red orbs after maxing out all weapons and magic?

Tags: god-of-war-ii

I have maxed out all the weapons and magic in God of War 2 PS2. I have completed the game and have started with the Bonus Play. I have even maxed out Blade of Olympus. What can I do with the red orbs I collect when I cannot upgrade any weapons or magic with them ?

Comment: Look at them. Lots of games have this problem where you run out of things to spend your resources on.